# Error while reading a file after creat system call

Tags: c, linux

I am creating a file in read/write mode and writing a string into it. Then I am trying to read it into a buffer where I get read error.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main()
{
    int fd,count,fd1;
    char buf[10];
    fd=creat("./smarak",S_IRWXU);
    if(fd<0)
    {
        perror("creat");
    }
    count=write(fd,"Hello smarak",7);
    printf("count=%d\n",count);
    count=read(fd,buf,7);
    printf("buf=%s\n",buf);
    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

---

I get nothing in buf and also count is -1 which is read error. Why this error? Isn't it possible to read a file created by creat() system call?

Answer (score 3):

You need to reposition between writing and reading:

```
 count=write(fd,"Hello smarak",7);
 printf("count=%d\n",count);

 // added:
 if ( lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_SET ) < 0 )
 {
     perror("lseek");
 }

 count=read(fd,buf,7);
 printf("buf=%s\n",buf);
 printf("%d\n",count);
```

After your write, the current position in the file is right after what you have written. If you want to read that back in, you have to "rewind" the current position to the beginning of the file.

Check [`man lseek`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek) for details.

And I don't know how Unix calls handle this, but the C standard (C99, 7.19.5.3 The `fopen` function, section 6) has this to say:

> [...] output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning
>   function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly
>   followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning
>   function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

So you *might* be looking at undefined behaviour in your code sample.

Comment: By Adding lseek also read error is coming up. It's not reading anything.

Comment: @SMARAKMISHRA: Ah... missed that. `creat()` opens the file as `O_WRONLY`, so you cannot read from it at all. (As usual, the information is right there in [man creat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/creat).) If you need to reposition-and-read, take Chandru's advice and use `open()` with `O_CREAT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

use `lseek()` function to set the position to the specified.

Try to use `open()` system call  instead of `creat()` system call.

When you use `creat()` it will open the process as

```
root@Lenovo-G585:/proc/6988/fd$ ls -la
total 0
dr-x------ 2 root root  0 Sep 18 16:20 .
dr-xr-xr-x 8 root root  0 Sep 18 16:20 ..
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 18 16:20 0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 18 16:20 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 18 16:20 2 -> /dev/pts/4
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 18 16:20 3 -> /tmp/smarak
 ^
```

Look ^ here.

The read permission is missing so you cannot able to read from that file.
If you use `open()` system call like

```
fd=open("./smarak",O_CREAT|O_RDWR);

O_CREAT - Which is used to create a new file if doesn't exist.
O_RDWR  - Which is used to open a file for read and write mode.
```

By using open with the given argument, you can do your requirement.
When using creat() it will open the file in O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC.

```
O_TRUNC - Which is used to truncate remove the file content and keep 
          the cursor position in start of file.
```

**Note:** While using `creat()` it will truncate the file if already exist.

Comment: Ya It's understood that read is not happening due to the absence of read permission flag. So Is it true that we can not read using creat(). If no please give one example.